# matching values of a node with the following sibling nodes if any

Tags: xpath

I need to know if there is any way to match the value of a particular node with all other values of that particular node in all other following sibling nodes.
To make it clear, if the scenario is like this

```
<A>
<name>tom</name>
<age>21</age>
</A>
<A>
<name>tom</name>
<age>24</age>
</A>
```

what if Node A may repeat any number of times and i need to check if there is any other value of the node  Tom i.e. Whichever  value comes in first node. If there is any other value of the node i need to pass 'Too many names' hard coded in the node .

I am very new to xslt. Is there any way out to solve this ? 
Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
<xsl:template match="A[name = following-sibling::A/name]">Too many names</xsl:template>
```

then you get the output `Too many names` for each `A` element which has a `name` child value equal to the `name` of any following sibling `A` element.

If you only want to check a certain value then use

```
<xsl:template match="A[name = 'tom' and 'tom' = following-sibling::A/name]">Too many names</xsl:template>
```