# Matching values of a node with the following sibling nodes

Tags: xslt

Here is the code xml snippet I am trying with :

```
<Shipment>
<Operation>Insert</Operation>
<Creation_Date>2013-12-02</Creation_Date>
<Line_Id>10023<Line_Id>
<Country_of_origin>US</Country_of_origin>
</Shipment>
<Shipment>
<Operation>Insert</Operation>
<Creation_Date>2013-12-3</Creation_Date>
<Line_Id>10023<Line_Id>
<Country_of_origin>US</Country_of_origin>
</Shipment>
<Shipment>
<Operation>Update</Operation>
<Creation_Date>2013-12-3</Creation_Date>
<Line_Id>10023<Line_Id>
<Country_of_origin>US</Country_of_origin>
</Shipment>
```

In this case where Value of the field  is same in all the Shipement tags, we need to pass the value as it is i.e Country_of_origin should be passed as US .

But if in any of the Shipement node, the Value of the field  is anything else than the value of first , it should be passed as null.

For example :

```
<Shipment>
<Operation>Insert</Operation>
<Creation_Date>2013-12-02</Creation_Date>
<Line_Id>10023<Line_Id>
<Country_of_origin>US</Country_of_origin>
</Shipment>
<Shipment>
<Operation>Insert</Operation>
<Creation_Date>2013-12-3</Creation_Date>
<Line_Id>10023<Line_Id>
<Country_of_origin>US</Country_of_origin>
</Shipment>
<Shipment>
<Operation>Update</Operation>
<Creation_Date>2013-12-3</Creation_Date>
<Line_Id>10023<Line_Id>
<Country_of_origin>FR</Country_of_origin>
</Shipment>
```

In this case Value of the field Country_of_origin should be passed as NULL as the  Country_of_origin  field value in third shipment tag  is carrying different value(FR) than first one (US).

Can anybody help on this ? Here The shipment tag can come n number of times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [matching values of a node with the following sibling nodes if any](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302733/matching-values-of-a-node-with-the-following-sibling-nodes-if-any)

Answer (score 2):

I'd define a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="country"
    select="(Shipment/Country_of_origin)[1]
             [not(. != ../../Shipment/Country_of_origin)]" />
```

If all the shipments have the same country of origin, the variable will be set to that value, if they don't then it will be set to the empty string (well, technically it will be set to either the `Country_of_origin` element from the first shipment, or to an empty node set/sequence, but when converted to string you'll get the values you need).  There's a redundant check here of the first `Shipment` against itself, but since that will never be `!=` it doesn't affect the result.

Now you simply use this variable value as the content of `Country_of_origin` for all the shipments.

You say in a comment that your real XML has several of these Shipment sections:

```
<Header>
  <Line>
    <Shipment>...</Shipment>
    <Shipment>...</Shipment>
    ...
  </Line>
  <Line>...</Line>
</Header>
```

and you need to do this process for each `Line` individually.  In that case you can't use a global variable but instead need to calculate the appropriate value at the right place and then pass it down the chain in template parameters.  In XSLT 2.0 this is easy using tunnel parameters:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Line">
    <xsl:next-match>
      <xsl:with-param name="country" tunnel="yes"
            select="(Shipment/Country_of_origin)[1]
                    [not(. != ../../Shipment/Country_of_origin)]" />
    </xsl:next-match>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Country_of_origin">
    <xsl:param name="country" tunnel="yes" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="$country" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In 1.0 you don't have tunnel parameters, so you have to pass the parameter down explicitly at every level, and you don't have `next-match` so you have to use `call-template`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="ident">
    <xsl:param name="country" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
        <xsl:with-param name="country" select="$country" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Line">
    <xsl:param name="country" />
    <xsl:call-template name="ident">
      <xsl:with-param name="country"
            select="(Shipment/Country_of_origin)[1]
                    [not(. != ../../Shipment/Country_of_origin)]" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Country_of_origin">
    <xsl:param name="country" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="$country" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is not working for the scenario.As the hierarchy is xslt is like : <Header><Line>--MultipleTimes--<Shipement>--Multiple Times<Country_of_origin></Country_of_origin></Shipemnt></Line></Header> ... So the variable declared here is not working. Kindly help.

Comment: yes. Here I have to calculate the variable for each line separately.

Comment: @user3052531 you'll need to adjust the paths to match your real XML, e.g. `select="(/Header/Line/Shipment/Country_of_origin)[1][not(. != ../../Shipment/Country_of_origin)]"`

Comment: Is there any way I can calculate this scenario with following:sibling:: ? Actually I am not aware of how to use following: sibling . Can you help on this ?

Comment: @user3052531 are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?